# Questions about Installing Ubuntu by Replacing a Drive where Win10 is installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have some experience with Linux systems. Now I want to install Ubuntu to my notebook. Since I just can't loose any data or crash my Notebook I have a few questions regarding the installation, for which I couldn't find any answers.

Currently I have Windows 10 running on my Notebook. In my notebook is no space for a second hard drive, therefore I want to replace my disk and install Ubuntu on the new one. I just want to be sure that this idea does not destroys my BIOS at all and I am still able to just switch to the old disk and run Windows again. Does that work?

(I am not concerned about data loss, because all my data is on a NAS. I chose this option to install Ubuntu because this way I have more available space than partitioning my old hard drive and I think it should be easier to go back to Windows in case anything goes wrong.)

Looking forward to hear from you (: Thanks!

Comment: If replacing a drive "destroyed BIOS" you wouldn't need to ask because it would be all over the news.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yeah that's obvious, but from my understanding I would be still able to just replace the Ubuntu drive and then boot Windows again, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's actually what many users do when they buy a new computer with Windows preinstalled and intend to run Ubuntu or other distros and then later resell it. They remove and store the original drive and put it back before selling.

Comment: Ok that sounds perfect. Thanks!
What would be the steps to install. Which option would I use when the installation process is asking my if I either want to replace Win, erase the disk or some thing else?

Comment: In a blank drive it won't present any "install alongside" option. Option will be, besides LVM+LUKS (for encryption), the usual erase and install (automated partitioning and installation) and "something else" (manual partitioning).

Comment: The drive is not blank. Some years ago I used it in my notebook before switching to a bigger drive. Probably that's why this option shows up.
Since I don't need any data on said drive I guess you would recommend me to use the erase and install option?

Comment: Indeed, if you don-t want a dual-boot then "erase and install" is the way.

Comment: No, for now, I don't want a dual boot system.
Thanks for your quick help! Faster than I expected!

Comment: Can also think of installing Ubuntu on a drive connected by USB, unless your drives can be replaced by a push button.

Comment: No, I have to open everything up and unscrew the drive, which takes some minutes. Does that have any big influence on the performance? 
Maybe connecting the drive with esata would be even better?

Comment: eSATA should have the same speed/performance as internal SATA of the same generation (and same technology). And new USB3.x external SSD drives are better than an old SATA HDD so yes, a Linux distro running from external media is an option to consider for those that can't or won't mess with internal drives. Setting it up is slightly more complicated though as Ubuntu tends to install the bootloader always in the first drive so, even without the external drive there will be Ubuntu .efi files in the internal drive's ESP (they can be easily removed if it must be, harmless otherwise)

Comment: Thanks! For now I will install Ubuntu as I initially suggested and then maybe later switch to the USB/esata option, if I am not able to get rid of Win10 ;)

Comment: Note that UEFI often forgets boot entry when a drive is disconnect. Most seem to auto find a Windows boot entry in the ESP - efi system partition, but rarely find Ubuntu/grub boot entries. You have to use efibootmgr or reinstall grub to add entry back into UEFI. Some will boot the fallback/drive entry at /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is like how an external drive boots.